# How to put a variable in an array?

Tags: regex, perl

i am dealing a with a csv file which is full of lines like these

```
   "ATSMM","CCC","43 676 017111 / 017113"
   "AERCM","XXX","54 320071 0900 / 0999"
```

and at the moment the script im using is able to recognize the number before the "/" and the number after it.

```
  my ($data, $start, $end) = m|(.* )(\d+) / (\d+)|;
```

the code above saves in **$data** the text before the number in front of the "/" 
the number before the / in **$start** and the number after in **$end**. My plans to sort this was to put each number which is in $start in an arrary1 and each number which is stored in $end in array2. This is aimed to seperate each number digit by digit so i can list down a range.

i am using perl scripts but any other options are welcome.

Thanks !!

Comment: Sounds like a classic XY-problem. If you need to parse csv data with quoted fields, maybe you should look at a csv parser, like [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV).

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is.  Are you looking for `push @starts, $start; push @ends, $end` or am I completely misunderstanding the problem statement?

Comment: You can _collect_ the pair as a record in an array of references, and _still_ sort the array using a field in the record. It's tricky looking syntactically, but easily done. Basically a `push @ary,  [ $2, $3 ];`

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
 my ( @array1, @array2 );    
 while (...) {
     my ($start, $end) = ...;
     push @array1, $start;
     push @array2, $end;
 }

 my @sorted_indexes = sort {
    $array1[$a] <=> $array1[$b]
       ||
    $array2[$a] <=> $array2[$b]
 } 0..$#array1;
 @array1 = @array1[@sorted_indexes];
 @array2 = @array2[@sorted_indexes];
```

With a proper CSV parser:

```
 use Text::CSV_XS qw( );

 my ( @array1, @array2 );    
 my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1 });
 while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
     my ($start, $end) = $row->[2] =~ /(\d+) \/ (\d+)/
        or die("Bad data");

     push @array1, $start;
     push @array2, $end;
 }
```

---

By the way, many avoid parallel arrays and would prefer

```
 my @array;    
 while (...) {
     my ($start, $end) = ...;
     push @array, [ $start, $end ];
 }

 @array = sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] || $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } @array;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for this:

```
my ($start, undef, $end) = m{"((\d|\s)+) / (\d+)"};
```

It is more specific on the `"`-s, so it finds the third item in your csv line.
It also uses `{` and `}` for quoting, because `|` is used for specifying alternatives in the pattern.
There are three submatches in the pattern (three pairs of `()`, two nested), but we use the second (the nested one) only to apply the quantifier `+` to the alternatives (digits or spaces), so we discard that submatch result with assigning it to `undef` on the left.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect the pair as a record in an array of references, and still sort the array using a field in the record. It's tricky looking syntactically, but easily done. Basically a `push @ary, [ $2, $3 ];`

Then to sort the records by a particular field you could do this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = "\n";

my $line;
my @records = ();

while ( $line = <DATA> ) {
  if ($line =~ m|(.* )(\d+) / (\d+)|) {
    push @records, [$2, $3];
  }
}

sub getSortedRecords {
  my ( $field, $direction ) = @_;
  return sort {
      my($r1, $r2) = ($a, $b);
      ($r1, $r2) = ($b, $a) if $direction cmp 'descending';
      $$r1[ $field ] <=> $$r2[ $field ];
  } @records;
}

print "Ascending, fld 0\n";
for ( getSortedRecords( 0, 'ascending' ) ) {
  print $$_[0], " / ", $$_[1], "\n";
}

print "\nAscending, fld 1\n";
for ( getSortedRecords( 1, 'ascending' ) ) {
  print $$_[0], " / ", $$_[1], "\n";
}

print "\nDescending, fld 0\n";
for ( getSortedRecords( 0, 'descending' ) ) {
  print $$_[0], " / ", $$_[1], "\n";
}

print "\nDescending, fld 1\n";
for ( getSortedRecords( 1, 'descending' ) ) {
  print $$_[0], " / ", $$_[1], "\n";
}


__DATA__
"ATSMM","CCC","43 676 1 / 4"
"AERCM","XXX","54 320071 2 / 3"
"ATSMM","CCC","43 676 3 / 2"
"AERCM","XXX","54 320071 4 / 1"
```

Out >>

```
Ascending, fld 0
4 / 1
3 / 2
2 / 3
1 / 4

Ascending, fld 1
1 / 4
2 / 3
3 / 2
4 / 1

Descending, fld 0
1 / 4
2 / 3
3 / 2
4 / 1

Descending, fld 1
4 / 1
3 / 2
2 / 3
1 / 4
```